# How to prefilter a jQuery DataTable?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I need to create a datatable that only displays records that have only one Activity Phase equal to "Waiting". Currently, the following solution displays all records, some of which have multiple Activity Phases. The first Activity Phase in the workflow is "Waiting".

Actions:

```
    public JsonResult LoadWaitList()
    {
        return Json(new { data = GetWaitList() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private IEnumerable GetWaitList()
    {
        var waitList = from a in _db.Applications
                       select new
                       {
                           a.AppNumber, ApplicationType = a.ApplicationType.Label,
                           ActivityPhases = a.ApplicationActivityPhas.Select(p => p.ActivityPhas.ActivityPhase).ToList(),
                           a.Id
                       };

        return waitList;
    }
```

DataTable:

```
        $("#WaitListDataTable").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("LoadWaitList", "Application")',
                datatype: "json",
                type: "GET"
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "AppNumber",
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        var applicationDetails = '@Url.Action("Details", "Application")/' + row.Id;
                        return '<a href=\"' + applicationDetails + '">' + data + '</a>';
                    }
                },
                { data: "ApplicationType" },
                { data: "ActivityPhases" },
                { data: "Id" }
            ]
        });
```

Index Table:

```
    <div class="pt-2">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-sm" id="WaitListDataTable">
            <thead class="table-info">
                <tr>
                    <th>Application Number</th>
                    <th>Application Type</th>
                    <th>Activity Phase</th>
                    <th>Id</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since "Waiting" is the first activity phase in the workflow, to display application records that only have one activity phase equal to "Waiting", I added the following:

```
public JsonResult LoadWaitList()
{
    return Json(new { data = GetWaitList() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private IEnumerable GetWaitList()
{
    var waitList = (from a in _db.Applications
                   select new
                   {
                       a.AppNumber, ApplicationType = a.ApplicationType.Label,
                       ActivityPhases = a.ApplicationActivityPhas.Select(p => p.ActivityPhas.ActivityPhase).ToList(),
                       a.Id
                   }).Where(p => p.ActivityPhases.Count() == 1);

    return waitList;
}
```